# Mysql INSERT INTO doesn't insert into database with variables but does without

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have been trying and trying but I have no idea what is wrong with my code.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../database.php');
$to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to']);
$from = $_SESSION['username'];
$msg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['msg']);
$subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']);
echo $to, $from, $msg, $subject;
$_SESSION['to'] = $to;
$_SESSION['msg'] = $msg;
$_SESSION['subject'] = $subject;
$err = array( );
$errflag = false;
if ($to = '') {
    $err[ ] = 'Missing To.';
    $errflag = true;
}
if ($from = '') {
    $err[ ] = 'Please Login.';
    $errflag = true;
}
if ($msg = '') {
    $err[ ] = 'Missing Message.';
    $errflag = true;
}
if ($subject = '') {
    $err[ ] = 'Missing Subject.';
    $errflag = true;
}
if ($errflag = true) {
    $_SESSION['mailerr'] = $err;
    //header('Location: send.php');
}
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mail(id, subject, to, from, msg) VALUES(NULL,'" . $subject . "', '" . $to . "', '" . $from . "', '" . $msg . "')");
if ($result) {
    echo "No Errors";
} else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
//header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

When I manually insert data instead of the variables it works but when I try with the variables it doesn't.

Also the error I get

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your  MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'to, from, msg) VALUES(NULL, '', '', '', '')' at line 1
```

Here is send.php

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
   <table border="0">
      <tr>
         <td>Subject:</td>
         <td><input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['subject'])){echo $_POST['subject'];}else if(isset($_SESSION['subject'])){echo $_SESSION['subject']; unset($_SESSION['subject']);}?>"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>To:</td>
         <td><input type="text" id="to" name="to" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['to'])){echo $_POST['to'];}else if(isset($_SESSION['to'])){echo $_SESSION['to']; unset($_SESSION['to']);}?>"/></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <?php if(isset($_POST['old'])){echo "<textarea disabled=disabled rows='8' cols='20'>".$_POST['old']."</textarea><br />";}?>
   <input type="text" name="msg" />
   <br />
   <input type="submit" name="msg" id="msg" value="Send"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea what the error is I've tried everything. It is also only this page. When I did it for everything else it works just fine.

Comment: note you have `<input type="text" name="msg" />` and `<input type="submit" name="msg" id..`. Look at the names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you use

```
if($from = ''){
```

everywhere.

change it to:

```
if($from == ''){
```

that way you compare the variable, and not set it....

Plus you use reserved keywords in your mysql query. Backticks can solve that.

```
INSERT INTO mail(`id`, `subject`, `to`, `from`, `msg`)
```

Another tip: use PDO or mysql with prepared statements for new projects. If there is a `'` in $subject, you also get this error (although you seem to escape it).

Comment: nice to copy my solution :)

Comment: @echo_me Not really, your forgot FROM + you did not mention the other mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

`TO` and `FROM` are reserved keyword for mysql

try use backticks

```
 INSERT INTO mail(id, subject, `to`, `from`, msg)
```

Comment: also from is reserved keyword

Comment: you welcome ! nice that i could help you